# jquery masked input make first two digits as non-editable

Tags: jquery, input-mask

Hi I'm currently using the jquery masked input and I want to make the first two digits as permanent numbers. For example, I have a number like `(09)191-234-567`

`(09)` are permanent mask while the following 9 digits are editable.

IF I do this, `$("#phone").mask("(99) 999-999-999");` all digits are editable. I tried searching but found no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [maskedinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.maskedinput) plugin  (which I believe you're referring to) allows you to define your own masks.

This means you can add your own masking character for numbers (`#`, for example), and remove the masking definition for `9` so that it no longer does anything.

```js
$.mask.definitions['#'] = $.mask.definitions['9'];  //Set # to do what 9 does
$.mask.definitions['9'] = null;                     //Remove 9 as a masking character
$("input").mask("(09) ###-###-###");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I gotta ask, how come the zero is not editable given that 9 is the only one defined.

Comment: By default, the `9` character is the numeric mask, however `0` has no significance - it already behaves as you need it to in your example. We only need to remove the definition for `9`.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So that makes sense. Thanks again sir

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `<script src="~/Root/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>` plugin, in order to set 0 and 9 in the mask e.g. +09 ### ### ## then you need to set the translations for 0 and 9 to null.

```
 $('.' + className).mask('+09 ### ### ##', {
        translation: {
            '0': null,
            '9': null,
            '#': { pattern: /\d/, recursive: true },
        }
    });
```