# How to make input first digit non-editable

Tags: jquery, mask

I have to try input mask. My value is 0 (111) 21312 321 32. My stock value always start with 0. I have a input mask plugin but i cant find in docs. How can i do that?

```
        jQuery(document).on("input", "#ed-editable", function() {
          jQuery(this).mask(
            '0(000) 0000 00 000',
            { placeholder: "0(___) ____ __ ___" }
      });
```

Comment: you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51413908/9560041)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery masked input make first two digits as non-editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413800/jquery-masked-input-make-first-two-digits-as-non-editable)